# Подскажите, почему я получаю данную ошибку? AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_command'

Tags: python, ооп, атрибуты, txt, строки

Подскажите, почему я получаю данную ошибку? **`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_command'`**. Дело в том, что точно такая же запись метода det_command(), но вне класса Server, работает и записывает в текстовый файл данные пользовательского ввода.
Вот пример кода:

```
path_to_file = "qwerty.txt"


class Server:
    def get_command(self):
        abc = input("Введите значение:::")
        return abc


class Handler:
    def change_file(self, server_1):
        with open(path_to_file, 'w') as f:
            result = server_1.get_command()
            f.write(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    a = server.get_command()

    handler = Handler()
    handler.change_file(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Лучше давайте полный трейсбэк ошибки.
А дело в том, что `a` у нас после `a = server.get_command()` это обычная строка с ввёденными в `input` данными.
Потом `a` передаётся в метод `change_file` как аргумент `server_1`. И вы пытаетесь у этой строки вызвать метод `get_command()`, которой у неё нет. Отсюда и ошибка.

По поводу вашего вопроса в комментарии ниже даю вариант. Чтобы сохранить введенные данные классу можно добавить атрибут через `self`

```
path_to_file = "qwerty.txt"


class Server:
    def get_command(self):
        self.abc = input("Введите значение:::")


class Handler:
    def change_file(self, data_to_write):
        with open(path_to_file, "w") as f:
            f.write(data_to_write)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    server.get_command()
    handler = Handler()
    handler.change_file(server.abc)
```

Или как делали вы, но немного ошиблись:

```
path_to_file = "qwerty.txt"


class Server:
    def get_command(self):
        abc = input("Введите значение:::")
        return abc


class Handler:
    def change_file(self, server):
        with open(path_to_file, "w") as f:
            data_to_write = server.get_command()
            f.write(data_to_write)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    handler = Handler()
    handler.change_file(server)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, подскажите, есть ли какой-то правильный способ сохранить пользовательский ввод в переменной одного класса, а затем записать его в текстовый файл в другом?

Comment: @SVC_1_1 Добавил в ответ. Но в целом тут ООП не очень-то нужен. А если это для учебных целей, то лучше начните с какой-нибудь книжки или статьи и повторяйте за автором. Ну чтобы базовый опыт работы с классами какой-то появился.

Comment: Спасибо большое за вариант. Ну в целом это для учебных целей, но для реализации задач немного большего проекта, поэтому решил попробовать прогнать подзадачу на таком примере.

Answer (score 2):

Когда Вы вызываете функцию *handler.change_file(a)*, в качестве параметра *server_1* Вы передаёте значение переменной *a*, которая является строкой (тип "string"). Потом внутри этого метода Вы пытаетесь у этой строки вызвать метод *get_command*, которого у строки нет.

Когда Вы вызываете метод *server.get_comnand()*, Вы вызываете его у объекта класса *Server*, который этот метод имеет.